# Deserialize JSon with RestSharp where the name starts with an @

Tags: c#, json, json.net, restsharp

I have a json response from an API that returns back with a name value where which starts with an @.

For example:

```
{
  "@id": "Something",
  "url": "www.example.com",
  "username": "Bob",
}
```

I am trying to load this with the generic GetAsync method into an object like:

```
RestClient restClient = new RestClient("https://api.somewebsite.com/pub");
var request = new RestRequest($"user/Bob");
var actUser = await restClient.GetAsync<User>(request)
```

This is working fine for all name/value pairs, but I cannot get RestSharp to initialize `@id`.

In my User class I have tried:

```
public string id { get; set; }
```

and

```
[JsonProperty("id")]
public string ID { get; set; }
```

and

```
[JsonProperty("@id")]
public string ID { get; set; }
```

but it is always null.

Is there a way to get the `@id` value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this, it works for me

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

var restResponse = await restClient.ExecuteTaskAsync(request);
User user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>( restResponse.Content);

public class User
{
    [JsonProperty("@id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
}
```

I think GetAsync uses Text.Json so you can try

```
    [JsonPropertyName("@id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
```

but IMHO ExecuteTaskAsync is more flexible since you can use any Newtonsoft.Json or System.Text.Json options.

Comment: I have tried it out and it is working. Thanks. So basically restClient.GetAsync<User>() is not working, but JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>() does. That means GetAsync is not taking into account the JsonProperty tag?

Comment: @Crick3t I think GetAsync uses Text.Json that has a lot of bugs. But you can try JsonPropertyName for example and let me know.

Comment: that works. So GetAsync needs JsonPropertyName.
Can you add these informations to your answer, please?